# Present the prev and next relations to current todo

Tags: emacs, org-mode

It seems that org-todo are good at displaying and remindering tasks but loose at express their logic relations.

Suppose  working on Task E.

```
* TODO Task E
```

In the middle of Task E, I realse its prev-task D should be get done in advance.
thus, I setup a new task

```
* PREV Task D
E.org::* TODO Task E
```

Since the task is set in another file from where Task E reside, so a link to E is added.

However,the current job E isn't aware of there exist some prev links to it. So
manual jobs are mondatory to insert Prev links to E:

```
* TODO Task E
D.org::* PREV Task D
```

When things get complicted with more prev jobs and next jobs bound to current task, even worse the current task itself work as prev or next to other project.

The interwinded relations implemented by manual jobs are  disaster.

I am not very familar with some magic functions like containers etc then have to express the logic relation with inserting links by labor.

Is there any solutions to the problem?

Comment: Maybe [TODO Dependencies](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html#TODO-dependencies) can help?

Comment: One way around the problem is to use one file for all your tasks. When you add a task to that file, all sub-tasks required to complete that task can go underneath (as subheadings), in which case all sub-tasks are "linked" to the parent task. The real magic is how you (1) capture new tasks and (2) display those tasks in a way that's meaningful to you (see `org-agenda-prefix-format`).

Comment: it only works in a single file. @NickD

Comment: That's correct: I don't think there is any provision for linking arbitrary tasks in a dependency graph in core Org mode (although there might be add-ons that implement something like it). Org mode's view is that if tasks are related, they should be together: a parent task with subtasks  (in which case, the dependencies ref I gave above would work).

Comment: One possibility for an add-on: [org-edna](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org-edna.html).

Comment: You might also look at [Karl Voit's notes on org-depend](https://karl-voit.at/2016/12/18/org-depend/) - they are several years old, but I don't think much has changed in the meantime.

Comment: could please transmit the comments to answer @NickD

Comment: I'll try to summarize but it won't happen soon: I'm really busy.